# How can I use Java variable in HTML tag in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying the following code in my .jsp file:

```
<select>
    <%DBHandler db= new DBHandler();%>
    <%db.init();%>
    <%String[] res= db.getExpertise();%>
    <% for(int i=0;i< res.length;i++){ %>

        <option value="<%=res[i]%>"><%=res[i]%></option>
    <%}%>
</select>
```

But, I don't know how to assign value in a tag using a variable in java code.

Comment: Would you mind to start with a tutorial? E.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm - these basics are usually well described there.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help your problem;

**1. Directives**

```
<%@page language="java" %>
```

**2. Declarations**

```
<%!    
int radius = 7; 
double pi = 3.1415; 
%>
```

**3. Scriptlets**

```
<%
    String id, name, dob, email, address;

    id = request.getParameter("id");
    name = request.getParameter("name");
    dob = request.getParameter("dob");
    email = request.getParameter("email");
    address = request.getParameter("address");

    sessionEJB.addClient(id, name, dob, email, address);
 %>
```

**4. Expressions**

```
<%!    
double radius = 7; 
double pi = 22/7;    
double area()
{
    return pi*radius*radius;
}    
%>

<html>
  <body>
    Area of circle is <%= area() %>
 </body>
</html>
```